# Network Problems after creating network bridge

Tags: kvm-virtualization, netplan, network-bridge, ping

i wanted to install some virtual machines on my server using KVM so for this purpose i created a network bridge. so far so good...

My OS is **Ubuntu 20.04**.

I change the **01-netcfg.yaml** file in **/etc/netplan**:

before:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
   enp5s0:
    dhcp4: no
    addresses: [192.168.192.222/24]
    gateway4: 192.168.192.1
    nameservers:
     addresses: [8.8.8.8]
     search: [example.net]
```

to after:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd

  ethernets:
   enp5s0:
    dhcp4: false
    dhcp6: false
#    addresses: [192.168.192.222/24]
#    gateway4: 192.168.192.1
#    nameservers:
#     addresses: [8.8.8.8]
#     search: [example.net]
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp5s0]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.192.222/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.192.1
      mtu: 1500
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
      parameters:
        stp: true
        forward-delay: 4
```

i registered the bridge and i got no error whatsoever.

in /**etc/netplan** i got one **host-bridge.xml** file:

```
<network>
  <name>host-bridge</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0"/>
</network>
```

BUT... after some hours my ssh connection to the server vanished.
i went to the physical machine and made ping attempts:

**ping google.de -> sucesss**

**ping router -> error**

**ping other machine in LAN -> error**

Afterwards i played back my initial .yaml config file, applied netplan, rebooted...

Everything works again like a charm.

I reproduced this error after setting up the bridge again -> after some hours the same stuff happened.
Playing back the original .yaml files helped.

So it seems to me that the bridge is the cause of error.
Do you have any hint for me what could be the solution here?

***Below i send you the output of commands and Additional Files:***

Output of **ip a**:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:92:26:5d:0b:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.192.222/24 brd 192.168.192.255 scope global enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::692:26ff:fe5d:bb7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp3s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:a6:4e:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp3s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:a6:4e:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: enp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1b:21:a3:b3:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:92:26:5d:0b:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.192.222/24 brd 192.168.192.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::692:26ff:fe5d:bb7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of **ip route**:

```
default via 192.168.192.1 dev enp5s0 
default via 192.168.192.1 dev br0 proto static 
192.168.192.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.192.222 
192.168.192.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.192.222
```

Output of **netstat -rn**:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.192.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp5s0
0.0.0.0         192.168.192.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 br0
192.168.192.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp5s0
192.168.192.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 br0
```

Output of **networkctl -a status**:

```
● 1: lo                                                     
             Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
          Network File: n/a                                 
                  Type: loopback                            
                 State: carrier (unmanaged)                 
                   MTU: 65536                               
  Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1                                 
               Address: 127.0.0.1                           
                        ::1                                 

● 2: enp5s0                                                                      
             Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link                     
          Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp5s0.network           
                  Type: ether                                                    
                 State: routable (configuring)                                   
                  Path: pci-0000:05:00.0                                         
                Driver: r8169                                                    
                Vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.                          
                 Model: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
            HW Address: 04:92:26:5d:0b:b7 (ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.)                
                   MTU: 1500 (min: 60, max: 9200)                                
  Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1                                                      
      Auto negotiation: yes                                                      
                 Speed: 1Gbps                                                    
                Duplex: full                                                     
                  Port: mii                                                      
               Address: 192.168.192.222                                          
                        fe80::692:26ff:fe5d:bb7                                  
               Gateway: 192.168.192.1                                            
                   DNS: 192.168.192.1                                            
        Search Domains: fritz.box                                                
          Connected To: Wifi2ndFloor on port 18:e8:29:69:ae:23 (br0)             
                        n/a on port 2c:56:dc:72:32:0c                            
                        UBNT on port e0:63:da:17:95:2b (br0)                     

Aug 02 13:59:30 hal9999 systemd-networkd[2380]: enp5s0: Gained IPv6LL
Aug 02 15:21:21 hal9999 systemd-networkd[3548]: enp5s0: Gained IPv6LL

● 3: enp3s0f0                                                                                                                         
             Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link                                                                          
          Network File: n/a                                                                                                           
                  Type: ether                                                                                                         
                 State: no-carrier (unmanaged)                                                                                        
                  Path: pci-0000:03:00.0                                                                                              
                Driver: e1000e                                                                                                        
                Vendor: Intel Corporation                                                                                             
                 Model: 82571EB/82571GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller D0/D1 (copper applications) (PRO/1000 PT Dual Port Server Adapter)
            HW Address: 00:15:17:a6:4e:58 (Intel Corporate)                                                                           
                   MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9212)                                                                                     
  Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1                                                                                                           
      Auto negotiation: yes                                                                                                           
                 Speed: n/a                                                                                                           
                  Port: tp                                                                                                            

● 4: enp3s0f1                                                                                                                         
             Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link                                                                          
          Network File: n/a                                                                                                           
                  Type: ether                                                                                                         
                 State: no-carrier (unmanaged)                                                                                        
                  Path: pci-0000:03:00.1                                                                                              
                Driver: e1000e                                                                                                        
                Vendor: Intel Corporation                                                                                             
                 Model: 82571EB/82571GB Gigabit Ethernet Controller D0/D1 (copper applications) (PRO/1000 PT Dual Port Server Adapter)
            HW Address: 00:15:17:a6:4e:59 (Intel Corporate)                                                                           
                   MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9212)                                                                                     
  Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1                                                                                                           
      Auto negotiation: yes                                                                                                           
                 Speed: n/a                                                                                                           
                  Port: tp                                                                                                            

● 5: enp6s0                                                                           
             Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link                          
          Network File: n/a                                                           
                  Type: ether                                                         
                 State: no-carrier (unmanaged)                                        
                  Path: pci-0000:06:00.0                                              
                Driver: e1000e                                                        
                Vendor: Intel Corporation                                             
                 Model: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection (Gigabit CT Desktop Adapter)
            HW Address: 00:1b:21:a3:b3:8e (Intel Corporate)                           
                   MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 9212)                                     
  Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1                                                           
      Auto negotiation: yes                                                           
                 Speed: n/a                                                           
                  Port: tp                                                            

● 6: br0                                                                                       
               Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link                                 
            Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-br0.network                          
                    Type: bridge                                                               
                   State: routable (configured)                                                
                  Driver: bridge                                                               
              HW Address: 04:92:26:5d:0b:b7 (ASUSTek COMPUTER INC.)                            
                     MTU: 1500 (min: 68, max: 65535)                                           
           Forward Delay: 4s                                                                   
              Hello Time: 2s                                                                   
                 Max Age: 20s                                                                  
             Ageing Time: 5min                                                                 
                Priority: 32768                                                                
                     STP: yes                                                                  
  Multicast IGMP Version: 2                                                                    
    Queue Length (Tx/Rx): 1/1                                                                  
                 Address: 192.168.192.222                                                      
                          fe80::692:26ff:fe5d:bb7                                              
                 Gateway: 192.168.192.1 (AVM Audiovisuelles Marketing und Computersysteme GmbH)
                     DNS: 8.8.8.8                                                              

Aug 02 13:59:30 hal9999 systemd-networkd[2380]: br0: netdev ready
Aug 02 13:59:30 hal9999 systemd-networkd[2380]: br0: IPv6 successfully enabled
Aug 02 13:59:30 hal9999 systemd-networkd[2380]: br0: Link UP
Aug 02 13:59:38 hal9999 systemd-networkd[2380]: br0: Gained carrier
Aug 02 13:59:39 hal9999 systemd-networkd[2380]: br0: Gained IPv6LL
Aug 02 15:21:21 hal9999 systemd-networkd[3548]: br0: netdev ready
Aug 02 15:21:21 hal9999 systemd-networkd[3548]: br0: Gained IPv6LL
Aug 02 15:21:21 hal9999 systemd-networkd[3548]: br0: netdev exists, using existing without changing its parameters
Aug 02 15:21:21 hal9999 systemd-networkd[3548]: br0: IPv6 successfully enabled
```

**/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-br0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
MACAddress=04:92:26:5d:0b:b7
MTUBytes=1500
Kind=bridge

[Bridge]
ForwardDelaySec=4
STP=true
```

**/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-br0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Link]
MTUBytes=1500

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=192.168.192.222/24
Gateway=192.168.192.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
```

**/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp5s0.network**

```
[Match]
MACAddress=04:92:26:5d:0b:b7
Type=!vlan bond bridge

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=no
DNS=192.168.192.1
Domains=fritz.box
Bridge=br0

[DHCP]
CriticalConnection=true
ClientIdentifier=mac
RouteMetric=100
UseMTU=true
```

Adding the real interfaces mac adress in the .yaml file to both the interface and the bridge as suggested [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1879592) did not help.

**UPDATE2: ls -la /run/systemd/network/** output before applying the netplan:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  80 Aug  6 11:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 540 Aug  6 11:09 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 256 Aug  6 11:09 10-netplan-enp5s0.network
```

and **after** sudo netplan apply:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 100 Aug  8 15:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 560 Aug  8 15:38 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  81 Aug  8 15:38 10-netplan-br0.netdev
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 164 Aug  8 15:38 10-netplan-br0.network
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 192 Aug  8 15:38 10-netplan-enp5s0.network
```

The output of **10-netplan-br0.network**:

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Link]
MTUBytes=1500

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=192.168.192.222/24
Gateway=192.168.192.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
```

The output of **10-netplan-br0.netdev**:

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
MTUBytes=1500
Kind=bridge

[Bridge]
ForwardDelaySec=4
STP=true
```

Comment: Hello @jak83, could you please specify which versions of netplan.io and systemd you are using? `dpkg -l | grep netplan.io`, `dpkg -l | grep systemd`.
Also, how did you "register" the bridge? Did you call `netplan apply`, did you try to reboot with the new (bridged) YAML configuration in place?

In your `ip a` output you seem to have the same IP address for the ethernet interfaces as well as the bridge, this seems to be a conflict and I am not yet sure where this is from, as in your netplan YAML you commented the IP address definition of the ethernet interface...

Comment: Hello @Lukas, thanks for picking this one up! netplan is 0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.2; systemd is 245.4-4ubuntu3.2. yes i called "netplan apply" and rebooted. i also thought  having the same IP is strange...

Comment: Hello @jak83, the duplicate IPs are a problem. Also, your networkctl command logs "br0: netdev exists, using existing without changing its parameters", which should not be the case either. And the file "10-netplan-enp5s0.network" looks wrong... it should look much simpler, like this: `[Match]
Name=enp5s0

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=no
Bridge=br0`

Did you do manual modifications to those files? Can you show the output of `ls -la /run/systemd/network/` before and after calling `netplan apply`? Did you try any other way to setup the bridge? Is there any other YAML in `/etc/netplan/`?

Comment: I did no manual modification to the file.

Above you dan See "Update2:" ls -la /run/systemd/network/

Comment: Hey @jak83 Thank you for the updated information! Is there any other YAML file in `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`? Could you please also show the output of `cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp5s0.network` after running `netplan apply` in your "UPDATE 2", as the file you showed earlier matches on MAC address and uses DHCPv4, which is neither defined in you first, nor your 2nd YAML config; so this does not really match any of your netplan configs and I'm wondering where it comes from?? There must be something else going on or it might be a left-over config from previous attempts..

Comment: Hey @Lukas thank you for staying here with me and trying to help out.I think i had one .yaml file wiht MAC address binding - but honestly getting confused myself slowly...

Is there any wy to "reset" netplan and try again from scrath? Because else it could become some sort of "gordian knot"? 

Anyway tomorrow i will try this again andlet you know, but if a "reset" is possible i guess we have lesss variables to deal with...

Comment: Netplan basically resets itself at every reboot, only considering the current configuration in `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`. So if you delete any YAML config files from that directory, netplan should not configure anything. If there is any configuration happening regardless, it must come from somewhere else, outside of netplan's control.